# IMG tag with CSS background image - ie10 shows missing img box

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

I have two styles defined:

```
img.feedback-sprite-22{
    display:block;
    background:url(../img/feedback-sprite-22.png) 0px 0px scroll;
    height:22px;
    border:0 !important; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0 !important;
    z-index:0;
}

img.feedback-sprite-22:hover{
    background-position:0px -22px;
}

img.fb {
    display:inline; 
    margin:auto 0; 
    border: none !important; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And I display the image like so:

```
<img class='fb feedback-sprite-22' height='22' width='65'>
```

Works great in ff & chrome but not ie (i've tested ie10 and ie8). IE shows the image (is it a simple gradient), but also shows the square img missing box (see below). Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have no **src** in your **img** tag, which is needed.

Use **div** `<div class="fb feedback-sprite-22"></div>` instead of **img**. And define width and height in css. If you realy want to do it using css...

But in my opinion you should use clear img - like `<img src="/img/feedback-sprite-22.png" alt="">` and not background in css for element like this.

Comment: I set about to replace the img with a div, as you say and it is a valid solution. But it requires tweaking (I am overlaying divs and images) and it would be nice to not have to rewrite...

Comment: The solution to the problem is using src="blank.gif". The background image displays and the browser is happy finding an image. The background image is a sprite and give me flexibility to show states (e.g. hover).

Comment: But if you are using img element you have to define src. Without src there is no need of using img tag. As you said you should use blank.gif.

Comment: Yes, that is what I discovered in this process. Although, IE is the only browser I've come across which throws up a visual deterrent. The reason for a background image is that it scales properly. I am not always using a gradient. So I need to use both the background image and a blank src.

Comment: IE has its own point of view. :) But for real you might want to read html specification http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element . Img should have src (and alt as alternative). It doesn't matter that chrome, or firefox show it as you want - You just have to use src and alt in img, because it's better to do everything in proper way. (Your current problem is best example)

Answer (score 2):

If its just a gradient, why not using a CSS, gradient?
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

With support for every broweser including IE6-10

Comment: Cool. I didn't know it existed. I suppose I could define a 2nd gradient for the hover state. I prefer working in Photoshop and may try to plug in Photoshops numbers. I'm all for getting rid of image files. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer, I've discovered, as Choinek pointed out, is that `IMG` obviously has to have 'src' defined for IE. I assigned it to blank.gif and all is good. Since I already use a blank.gif on the site, it isn't another image to load.

However, I really like the idea of using a CSS gradient. This would reduce the number of images (always good).